# How To Set Up a Testing/Development/Staging/Production Environments for WordPress in Azure?

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have a WordPress App Service setup in Azure. I do not currently have a git repo where changes are being pushed, but I will be wanting to add one eventually that can be tracked. All the changes currently will be done in the Admin dashboard for wordpress. I want to create a process that dictates the workflow to deploy on the production site. The process needs to be able to handle daily changes from multiple team members to content but also handle plugin testing and updates in a dev environment.

I guess there are a few things that are confusing me with the process.

When using deployment slots for the staging/production environments, I know that when you want to implement new changes into the production environment, the staging and production environments swap. So, the staging is now in production and the old production is now a backup in staging. Here, I am confused, how do I then work off of the new production environment if I now have a backup in staging? Do I need another slot that doesn't get swapped but is updated whenever something is pushed to production, so, I can constantly develop on the newest content? If so, how would I go about making this slot?

For the plugin testing and updates, that will definitely be used in the staging environment, which will make changes to files/folders in the WP database. The daily content changes, would they be better done in production in the admin dashboard? This would make changes to the database as well, are all of the deployment slots using the same database? How do I make sure I am not overwriting content going either direction.

Currently, I am operating under the assumption that I will be using the deployment slots to do this, but I also have a dev web app service setup, so let me know if there is a better way to go about everything. I know this was a lot, but the process is confusing me and I appreciate any help on the matter.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it makes sense to manage a WordPress site like this. You're not deploying code, you are making configuration changes to an off-the-shelf product. You are, in effect, modifying data on your site, not modifying the site itself.

Find some WordPress site administration documentation, and do what it says. There has to be a process for testing and validating plugins in a production environment.

Comment: I want to add a git repo that holds everything and make changes eventually, does this change your answer?

Comment: I don't know how you'd do that. Can you explain how it would work?